# Drupal 8 libraires not showing style.css in view source?

Tags: drupal-8

I have included the style.css in libraries.yml. I have placed my custom.css in css/custom.css file. In view source can't find the css line in html. I have added my info.yml file. I have added the global-styling in info file.

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:  
      css/style.css: {}
      css/custom.css: {}
framework:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js: {}
```

info.yml

```
core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap

name: 'horizon'
description: 'Uses the Bootstrap framework Sass source files and must be compiled (not for beginners).'
package: 'Bootstrap'

libraries:
  - 'horizon/global-styling'

regions:
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
  header: 'Header'
  left_sidebar: Left Sidebar
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  main_content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'

libraries-extend:
  bootstrap/framework:
    - horizon/framework
```

Comment: Is the real problem that the CSS isn't included or applied on the page? Or is the CSS applied but just not visible in the page source?

Comment: css not showing i have included in the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I see two options.

1. When you create a library, you only create a reference. You need to specify somewhere to use this reference. If this is in your theme, I suggest you [add it](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) inside your theme.info.yml.
2. Did you clear your cache? If you didn't, the reference won't be updated. I think this is more likely to be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why i uncheck the checkboxes but after unchecking it is showing my custom.css style. I know that it is for imporving site performances compressing the css and js.
Configuration >> development >> performances >> unchecked Aggregate CSS files Aggregate JavaScript files

Answer (score 0):

I think you has checked css/js aggregation ON at `config>development>performance` page.

But if aggregation was ON then all custom CSS/JS and Drupal core CSS/JS should wrap into minimum files and you can't see CSS/JS file with name directly even style.css or any js file also.

Comment: yes you are right but my  style should applied to that html element. even after i give important it is not showing. So i disabeld the aggregate functions